# Perl: Escape special chars in a string to match a regex

Tags: regex, perl, escaping, special-characters

I'm writing bash functions to handle string operations with regexes. Bash built-in functions being very poor at the job, I'm using the perl command to do it.

For instance, here's my "strMatch" function (in bash):

```bash
# Usage: if (strMatch <string> <regex>); then...
function strMatch {
    local str="$1"
    local regex="$2"

    local perlCmd='if (qq('$str') =~ m/'$regex'/g) { print "0"; } else  { print "1"; }'
    return $(perl -e "$perlCmd")
}
```

Test string: `foo-bar\rLoading... xx%\rFile: "some-(filename.ext".`
regex: `-bar(?:.*?)File: "(.\*?)\.ext"`

Everything works fine except for one thing ; I can't find a way to properly escape special chars within the string to match (for some of them, at least).
I'm very new to Perl (except for regex syntax), so I tried various things found here and there without any success.

**with 'qq'** it doesn't handle '(', which is interpreted as a capturing group without a matching ')'. I'm guessing the same will happen with '['...
         =>
syntax error at -e line 1, near "qq(foo-bar\rLoading... xx%\rFile: "some-(filename.ext".) =~ m/-bar\r(?:.*?)File: "(.*?)\.ext"/g) { "
         =>
Can't find string terminator ")" anywhere before EOF at -e line 1.

**with 'quotemeta'** it's worse, breaks at ':', '%', '\r'... pretty much everything
         =>
Backslash found where operator expected at -e line 1, near "bar\"
         =>
Operator or semicolon missing before %

As a bonus, if I add 'w' or 'W' option to get perl warnings, it doesn't print anything!!! what's going on?

I just want the string to be able to contain pretty much anything including '%', '(', '[', '\r', '\n'... Anyone know how to do that??? What am I doing wrong ?

**EDIT: Answered**

Thank you **choroba**, using perl arguments $ARGV works like a charm. I also used a modified version of **ikegami**'s solution which is more elegant.

Function now goes like this:

```bash
# Usage: if (strMatch <string> <regex>); then...
function strMatch {
    local str="$1"
    local regex="$2"

    local perlCmd='exit 1 if ($ARGV[0] !~ m/$ARGV[1]/g)'
    perl -e "$perlCmd" "--" "$str" "$regex"
    return $?
}
```

Edit2: Added "--" to stop processing options.

Comment: `if (/.../g)` makes no sense and can result in subtle bugs. You want `if (/.../)`

Comment: I'm using if ($var =~ m/.../g) which works. What do you mean?

Comment: I'm not sure what needs clarification.

Comment: Removing `--` was also a bad idea. Now it will fail if the string to search starts with `-`.

Comment: Added the double dash. BTW, did you mean that using the global scope was useless because I don't care about multiple occurences ? If so, I know, it's because I copy-pasted it from my strGetMatches function...

Comment: I didn't say useless. I said it's a bug because makes no sense and that it can cause subtle errors.

Comment: I can't explain why it makes no sense, as that would require knowing why you think it makes sense and correcting that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the string and regex as parameters (I also simplified the Perl code):

```
#!/bin/bash
# Usage: if (strMatch <string> <regex>); then...
function strMatch () {
    local str="$1"
    local regex="$2"

    local perlCmd='print $ARGV[0] =~ m/$ARGV[1]/ ? 0 : 1'
    return $(perl -e "$perlCmd" "--" "$str" "$regex")
}
```

Tested with

```
~/test.sh $'foo-bar\rLoading... xx%\rFile: "some-(filename.ext"' '-bar(?:.*?)File: "(.*?).ext"'
```

Comment: Don't even need `print`: `perl -e'exit 1 if $ARGV[0] !~ m/$ARGV[1]/' -- "$str" "$regex"` // `return $?`

Comment: Thank you! That was helpful. It works, but not if use '\r' in the regex. '-bar.*?File: "(.*?)\.ext"' works but NOT '-bar\r.*?File: "(.*?)\.ext"'

Comment: Yes it does. Test: `if strMatch "$( echo -e 'foo\rbar' )" 'foo\rbar' ; then echo 'match' ; else echo 'no match' ; fi`

Comment: It doesn't when using a string literal, but it does work with -e, yes. It also works with '\\r'. I'm updating my original post

Comment: `\r` isn't suppose to match the two characters `\ ` and `r`; it's suppose to match a carriage return. If you want to match `\ ` and `r`, you need the pattern `\\r`. Test: `if strMatch 'foo\rbar' 'foo\\rbar' ; then echo 'match' ; else echo 'no match' ; fi`

Comment: Updated my OP with the answer. I can't even +1 thought, not enough reputation lol